# How to preview a form in another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a simple Form builder. I want to preview the existing forms to the users while they are selecting the forms(Like Subscribe Forms, Survey forms, etc.) with disabled empty fields(user shouldn't be able edit in preview). I am new to Js and CSS.

###### Example:

This my html file with form (form.html)

```
<form>
<input name="username" type="text">
<input name="email" type="text">
</form>
```

This is my target html file where i want to preview my form (index.html).

```
<body>
<h3>Select forms :</h3>
<button> Select form</button>
This is where i want to preview my Form from form.html
</body>
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!
Thank you.

Comment: Hi ! Do you know the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag ?

Comment: Use the answers to [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/215552), then find the `form` element and disable it.

Comment: Nope i have just seen it.! Is that  used  in this case? @Philippe

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for sharing it. Il check it out . @HereticMonkey

Comment: Just a way, but perfectible ;)